# Embedding a multiple page pdf into a site with user ability to flip between pages + additional features

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am looking for some general advice on where to start with a project. I am working on a journal website which will display a handwritten journal with the ability to switch between a typed transcript version via a switch button. I am coding the website from scratch and working within php.

- It will be around 70 pages long.
- Have the ability to switch between the pages via arrows or by typing in a page number.
- A switch that switches between the handwritten version and the typed transcript.

I have included some annotations of my designs below to give some more details of what I would like to achieve.

[image: annotated design hand written journal]

[image: annotated design transcribed journal]

Is there some kind of framework available that allows for embedding multiple page pdf into a site that I can then work from to achieve the ability to switch between the handwritten and transcribed version

I am a bit stuck on where to start - I am more of a designer :)

Thanks for taking your time to read

Nina :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common JS framework to embed PDF files in a webpage is pdf.js, you can find a demo here https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html. I have not used pdf.js but I don't think it allows for editing the PDF content, like the style and fontface. So you could create 2 pdf files, a handwrittin and a plain pdf and just switch the viewed files around with a button, or try styling the pages in HTML/CSS and not PDF's. If you are not that experienced with CSS I would recommend the former.

Hope it helps.

Edit: I am not sure if a clickable popup is possible inside of a PDF, if this is an important feature, you may have to choose the HTML/CSS path instead of the PDF path.

Comment: Sounds like a brilliant starting point. Thank you. Although I will probably opt for something opensource and free. I was thinking of doing something just using html and css but I thought embedding a multiple page pdf might be a cleaner option due to the large amount of pages included. But I might consider html + css.

Comment: @Ninoid PDF.js is an open source project developed by Mozilla at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js